# What is maximum value of $f(t)=16\cos t \cdot \cos 2t \cdot\cos 3t \cdot \cos6t$

Tags: trigonometry, optimization, maxima-minima

What is maximum value of $$f(t)=16\cos t \cdot \cos 2t \cdot\cos 3t \cdot \cos6t$$

**My Approach:**

$1. \;\;$Directly $t=0$ gives me maximum value of $16$.

$2.\;\;$ Converted it into $f(t)=\dfrac{\sin(4t)\sin(12t)}{\sin (t)\sin(3t)}\;\;$ but couldn't proceed further from this step.

**My Doubts:** $1.\;$Can we get maximum value without putting $t=0\;?$

$2.\;$ How can i proceed further using second method to get maximum value?

$3.\;$ Is there other way to solve this problem ?

Comment: I don't understand why you don't want to put $t=0$. Trying other methods makes no sense.

Comment: For your first question: since $\cos$ has period $2 \pi$, your function $f$ also has period $2 \pi$, so the answer is "yes": any integer multiple of $2 \pi$ will also yield 16. Dunno about your other two questions, though.

Comment: Don't know why i am getting downvotes to question.

Answer (score 10):

Observe that $\forall t, f(t) \le 16$ and $f(t) = 16$ when $t = 0$. This shows $16$ is the max value of $f$. All you need is $\cos(kt) \le 1$ for any $k,t$.

Comment: Two downvotes..? Just why, I don't think there is any error in this answer and this answers the question as well.

Comment: The answer is perfectly fine!

Comment: also don't know why downvotes to question too.

Answer (score 4):

I think you did not answer the interesting part of the problem: why **is** $t=0$ a maximum of $f$? Wang YeFei did answer this.

To answer your doubts/questions:

1. You cannot get the maximum value without evaluating the function at a maximum.
2. Your conversion of $f$ is not even defined at $t=0$. So this way can not work.
3. The usual way would be to find $f'$ to get all local extrema and pick the one with highest value as global maximum. But this would be unnecessaryly complicated here…

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question...

1. Yes, but it would involve setting $f'(t)=0$ - you can use logarithmic differentiation$^1$ to get the derivative or use the product rule multiple times.
2. Same as 1, but now you'd have to involve the quotient rule AND the product rule to get things moving.
3. You could graph the equation and see where the maxima are by inspection. Desmos or Geogebra would be a huge help here.

$^1$ To find the logarithmic derivative, we would have...

$$f(t) = 16 \cos t \cos 2t \cos 3t \cos 6t \\ \ln f(t) = \ln 16 + \ln \cos t + \ln \cos 2t + \ln \cos 3t + \ln \cos 6t \\ \frac {f'(t)}{f(t)} = 0 + \frac {1}{\cos t}(-\sin t) + \frac {1}{\cos 2t}(-2\sin 2t) + \frac {1}{\cos 3t}(-3\sin 3t) + \frac {1}{\cos 6t}(-6\sin t) \\ f'(t) = f(t) (-\tan t -2 \tan 2t - 3 \tan 3t - 6 \tan 6t) \\ f'(t) = 16 \cos t \cos 2t \cos 3t \cos 6t(-(\tan t +2 \tan 2t + 3 \tan 3t + 6 \tan 6t))$$  Setting $f'(t) = 0$, you would have either $$16 \cos t \cos 2t \cos 3t \cos 6t = 0$$ or $$-(\tan t +2 \tan 2t + 3 \tan 3t + 6 \tan 6t)= 0$$